# make a tabpanel-like with SVG elements

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm working with D3, and I'm trying to create two overlaid SVG elements and displaying only one at a time (a tab panel) but I really don't know how to overlay them.

I already tried to insert each SVG element into a < div> and set the display to inline, I also tried to directly set the SVG's display attribute to "inline" but none of these methods work, and now,I'm stuck !

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use HTML elements like `<div>` inside an SVG.  The CSS `display` property works in SVG, but only to turn the visibility of objects on and off.  The value `none` will hide an element, but all of the other values (`inline`, `block` etc) make an element visible.